# How to use function $switch inside of a $map in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I want to apply a case statement to each element of an array.
First, I'll put the array in the $map "input" argument and name it "c".
Then, inside the "in" argument, I'll apply the case using the $switch function.

This is getting me this error: Unrecognized expression '$$c.Id'. What am I doing wrong?

Query (aggregation) $project:

```
"Metric" : {
        "$map" : {
            "input" : "$Categories.Category.ReturnCodes.ReturnCode",
                "as" : "c",
                   "in" : { 
                      "$switch":
                          {
                             "branches": [
                                {
                                   "case": { "$$c.Id" : { "$in": [0] } },
                                   "then": "10"                 
                                },
                                {
                                   "case": { "$$c.Id" : { "$in": [101] } },
                                   "then": "9"
                                 }], "default": "99"}  
                    }  
            }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in `case` is incorrect, Your query should be:

```
"Metric": {
  "$map": {
    "input": "$Categories.Category.ReturnCodes.ReturnCode",
    "as": "c",
    "in": {
      "$switch": {
        "branches": [
          {
            "case": {
              $in: [
                "$$c.Id",
                [
                  0
                ]
              ]
            },
            "then": "10"
          },
          {
            "case": {
              $in: [
                "$$c.Id",
                [
                  101
                ]
              ]
            },
            "then": "9"
          }
        ],
        "default": "99"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Reference**

[`$switch`(aggregation) | MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/#behavior)